# Database Architecture problem with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I´m learning EF Core and I´m creating a simple repository with Films and Countries. This is the model class for the Films:

```
public class Film : IItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
  
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Genre> Genres { get; set; } = new();

    public int Rating { get; set; }

    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; } = new();
}
```

And this is the model class for the countries:

```
public class Country : IItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is that I want the user to select a country from a fixed list (50 predefined countries that I have selected). For that in the `OnModelCreating` method of my `DbContext`, I have added this code:

```
builder.Entity<Country>().HasIndex(x => x.Name).IsUnique();
builder.Entity<Country>().HasData(CountryMapper.Countries);
```

where `CountryMapper` provides the list of countries that I have selected.

The problem here is that EF created a foreign key in the `Countries` table to the `Film.Id` property. However as is prefilled the FK is always empty. This will also mean that a country can only be linked to one film, but I don´t want that as two different films can contain the same country.

How should I solve this? Does it even make sense to save the countries in the database if they are going to be fixed? What is the best way to achieve what I want?

Comment: It sounds like the `Country` is a fixed constant list - why not use a data type such as Enums instead? They map to integers in the database (by default).

Comment: @nbokmans Yeah I assume that this is the best way to go. This issue comes because at first I wanted be able to create a Country that is not in the list. But I still wanted to have the prefilled data. Do you know how can I achieve this?

Comment: As is, EF infers a many-to-one relationship. So one film can have many countries but each country only one film. You need to tell EF explicitly that it is actually a many-to-many relationship. The fact that countries will effectively never change doesn't matter. EF cannot know that and it is also irrelevant to this aspect of the schema.

Comment: ^^ that's also why the country table has a FK to Film table. That's how many-to- one is modeled. If you have many-to- many, there will probably be an extra table that models the relation between the two.

Comment: You need a third table to handle many to many relation between Film and Country.